# How to merge two linked lists in C

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am given two sorted linked lists in C, and I am trying to merge them together, so that they will be in sorted order. Can anyone tell me why my code doesn't work.

```
struct ListNode {
    int val;
    struct ListNode *next;
};

struct ListNode *mergeTwoLists(struct ListNode *l1, struct ListNode *l2) {

    struct ListNode *node;

    node = NULL;

    struct ListNode *n = (struct ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));

    node = n;

    while (l1 != NULL && l2 != NULL) {
        if ((*l1).val < (*l2).val) {
            (*n).val = (*l1).val;
            l1 = (*l1).next;
        } else {
            (*n).val = (*l2).val;
            l2 = (*l2).next;
        }
        (*n).next = (struct ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
        n = (*n).next;
    }
    if (l1 != NULL) {
        n = l1;
    }
    if (l2 != NULL) {
        n = l2;
    }
    return node;
}
```

Comment: You're not showing any test data, but your logic for when one list is exhausted is incomplete: it only works for one additional element in the remaining source list. You need to use loops here.

Comment: If you want to *zip* the original two lists there is no need for `malloc()`. Just juggle some pointers.

Comment: BTW: please don't write `(*foo).bar` instead of `foo->bar`. These two form are both 100% equivalent, but nobody uses the first form.

Comment: If you are merging 2 lists, you generally end up with a single new list comprised of the nodes of the original two and there is no need to allocate any additional memory, you are simply re-wiring pointers. You can, however, copy every node from the first two lists and put the copies together in a sorted list -- but they you remain responsible for freeing the nodes in all three lists when done. Which of those two options are you attempting to achieve? Please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

- First, decide if you want to merge the *original* lists, or you want to return a *copy* of the list(but with the same values)
- if you want a copy, there should be **exactly one** `malloc()` for every input node you pass. (you can verify that in the merge loop, either `l1` or `l2` is advanced, and one node is (possibly) allocated)

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct node {
        struct node *next;
        int val;
        };

#if WANT_CLONE
#include <stdlib.h>
struct node *clone(struct node *p)
{
struct node *q;
if (!p) return NULL;
q = malloc (sizeof *q);
*q = *p;
return q;
}

#define CLONE(x) clone(x)
#else
#define CLONE(x) (x)
#endif

struct node *merge(struct node *l1, struct node *l2)
{
struct node dummy = {NULL,0}, *here;

for(here = &dummy; l1 || l2; here = here->next) {
        if (!l2 || l1 && l1->val <= l2->val) {
                here->next= CLONE(l1); l1 = l1->next;
                }
        else    if(!l1 || l2) {
                here->next= CLONE(l2); l2 = l2->next;
                }
        }

return dummy.next;
}

        /* Some test data */
struct node evens[] = {
{evens+1, 0}, {evens+2, 2}, {evens+3, 4}, {evens+4, 6}, {NULL, 8}, };

struct node odds[] = {
{odds+1, 1}, {odds+2, 3}, {odds+3, 5}, {odds+4, 7}, {odds+5, 9}, {NULL, 11}, };

void print(struct node *p)
{
for( ; p; p = p->next) {
        printf(" %d", p->val);
        }
printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
struct node *both;

printf("odds:"); print(odds);
printf("evens:"); print(evens);
both = merge(odds, evens);
printf("both:"); print(both);

printf("odds:"); print(odds);
printf("evens:"); print(evens);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of merging the 2 lists, you are just creating a new list, copying values from both lists in increasing order, but you fail to copy the remaining elements when one if the lists is exhausted.

Note these extra remarks:

- you are probably expected to merge the lists in place and return a pointer to the head of the merged list.
- the syntax `(*l1).val` is not strictly incorrect in C, but the pointer syntax `l1->val` is considered much more readable.

Here is a modified version:

```c
struct ListNode {
    int val;
    struct ListNode *next;
};

struct ListNode *mergeTwoLists(struct ListNode *l1, struct ListNode *l2) {
    struct ListNode *head, *n;

    n = head = NULL;

    while (l1 != NULL && l2 != NULL) {
        if (l1->val <= l2->val) {
            if (n == NULL) {
                n = head = l1;
            } else {
                n = n->next = l1;
            }
            l1 = l1->next;
        } else {
            if (n == NULL) {
                n = head = l2;
            } else {
                n = n->next = l2;
            }
            l2 = l2->next;
        }
    }                
    if (l1 != NULL) {
        if (n == NULL) {
            head = l1;
        } else {
            n->next = l1;
        }
    } else {
        if (n == NULL) {
            head = l2;
        } else {
            n->next = l2;
        }
    }
    return head;
}
```